# My R for loop only prints the last element

Tags: r

I think I am overwriting my list for each iteration of my loop, I just can't work out how to fix it.

```
a <- c(-45, -345, 610, 23, 705)

for(i in a)
  if(i<0){
    angle = i + 360
  }else if(i>360){
    angle = i - 360
  }
print(angle)
```

the result is 345 (705 - 360) but i need all of them.

Comment: You are printing `angle` outside of the loop, so you only get the last value.

Comment: Hi..I just noticed that you unaccepted the answer. Was it by mistake or was there an issue with the answer?

Comment: Hello sorry this was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the values are being overwritten. You need to create a vector to store the values.

```
a <- c(-45, -345, 610, 23, 705)
angle <- numeric(length(a))

for(i in seq_along(a)) {
  if(a[i]<0){
    angle[i] = a[i] + 360
  }else if(a[i]>360){
    angle[i] = a[i] - 360
  } else {
    angle[i] <- a[i]
  }
}
angle
```

Also you can avoid `for` loop by using nested `ifelse` or `case_when` from `dplyr` package.

```
dplyr::case_when(a < 0 ~ a + 360, 
                 a > 360 ~ a - 360, 
                 TRUE ~ a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I was banging my head against a wall. That makes so much sense, and thank you for introducing me to dplyr, I knew there was a cleaner way of doing this, I will go learn more! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You could also avoid a loop using this vectorized operation. It's an alternative way to scale angles to the range 0-360.

```
a <- c(-45, -345, 610, 23, 705)
angle <- (a + 360) %% 360

angle
[1] 315  15 250  23 345
```